# Angular universal app loads very slow hosting on aws ec2

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I have angular universal app hosting on aws ec2 which suddenly start loading very slow. Sometimes it loads fast but sometimes it takes almost 10 sec to make the connection to server then starts loading the app. These images are not more than 15kb and its taking 2-3 sec just to load them. For the js file its taking 5-6 secs sometimes it takes 11 secs to load main js file and the size is only 357kb.

[image]

[image]

Can anyonce please suggest what is issue is it angular app that is causing the issue or aws ec2 and how can I fix this

Comment: so what is on the other side? nodejs with some framework? What is the instance type? Which region do you use and how far is it from the place where are you testing?

Comment: what do you mean otherside, the instance type is ec2 and it was working fine before its happening from last week

Comment: well, maybe it will start working again, but if you want any advice you have to provide more information about your configuration. What did you tested and ruled out as a possible problem? Maybe you test it from your local computer which is connected by w wi-fi with poor signal strength so half of the packets are lost. You provided no information about your setup, why do you think that anyone can possibly figure out what is the problem based on the information you have provided?

Comment: Do you experience this consistently, or only on first load? Perhaps your hosting VM is going to hibernate after 15 minutes

Comment: @Pieterjan on every load in incongito it load slow